# What kind of fork end is this?

Tags: frames, fork, internally-geared-hub

I am looking for a new city/urban bike and thought that a gear hub would be a nice addition (before this I was exclusively using derailleur gears). To get started I was reading the [wiki page on fork ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_end) to learn about some simple facts and what to pay attention to (especially like how to adjust the hub properly).

I found an [interesting bike](https://www.bulls-bikes.com/produkt/bulls-urban8s2-583-20048?sku=583-20048_ZEG) but I simply cannot tell what kind of fork end this might be (it doesn't seem to have one?!):[image: what fork end is this?]

It looks that one first has to add a fork end. Is this a good way - e.g. compared to a semi-horizontal dropout - to adjust the hub/chain combo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are adjustable dropouts. The main reason for these is that the disk brake caliper needs to be aligned with the disc. The adjustable part on the other side would have both disk brake mount and dropout so that they move together when the part is adjusted. For just adjusting cable tension these don't have practical benefits over horizontal dropouts.

Comment: Aha, interesting . the disc brake part makes perfectly sense. I only came across adjustable dropouts when reading about Rohloff hubs and they looked completely different. Would you consider this as fairly standard?

Comment: This is fairly standard with singlespeed / internal geared rear discs - which is a niche setup - and very unusual otherwise.